# Android: root and not root users see different mount options

Tags: android, shell, root, mount

I found out a strange behaviour on my android device.

Depending on the user (root or not root) asking for mounted filesytems, the mount options change:

[shell on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM8zR.png)

Another shell, same device, but from adb, the behavior instead is normal:

> **shell@D6503:/ $ mount | grep noatime**
>
> rootfs / rootfs rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime 0 0 tmpfs /dev tmpfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,size=1412768k,nr_inodes=161361,mode=755
>   0 0 devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,mode=600 0 0
>   proc /proc proc rw,noatime,nodiratime 0 0 sysfs /sys sysfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime 0 0 selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs
>   rw,noatime,nodiratime 0 0 debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs
>   rw,noatime,nodiratime 0 0 none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,size=1412768k,nr_inodes=161361,mode=750,gid=1000
>   0 0 tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,size=1412768k,nr_inodes=161361,mode=755,gid=1000
>   0 0 tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,size=1412768k,nr_inodes=161361,mode=755,gid=1000
>   0 0 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system ext4
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
>   /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0
>   0 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache /cache ext4
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
>   /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/apps_log /mnt/idd ext4
>   rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,discard,nobarrier,data=ordered
>   0 0 tmpfs /storage/remote tmpfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,size=1024k,nr_inodes=256,mode=750,gid=1028
>   0 0 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/LTALabel /lta-label ext4
>   ro,context=u:object_r:lta_label:s0,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,data=ordered
>   0 0 securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,noatime,nodiratime 0
>   0 /dev/fuse /mnt/shell/emulated fuse
>   rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0 /dev/block/vold/179:65 /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 vfat
>   rw,dirsync,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
>   0 0 /dev/block/vold/179:65 /mnt/secure/asec vfat
>   rw,dirsync,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
>   0 0 /dev/fuse /storage/sdcard1 fuse
>   rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0
>
> **shell@D6503:/ $ su
>
>   root@D6503:/ # mount | grep noatime**
>
> rootfs / rootfs rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime 0 0 tmpfs /dev tmpfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,size=1412768k,nr_inodes=161361,mode=755
>   0 0 devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,mode=600 0 0
>   proc /proc proc rw,noatime,nodiratime 0 0 sysfs /sys sysfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime 0 0 selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs
>   rw,noatime,nodiratime 0 0 debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs
>   rw,noatime,nodiratime 0 0 none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,size=1412768k,nr_inodes=161361,mode=750,gid=1000
>   0 0 tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,size=1412768k,nr_inodes=161361,mode=755,gid=1000
>   0 0 tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,size=1412768k,nr_inodes=161361,mode=755,gid=1000
>   0 0 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system ext4
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
>   /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0
>   0 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache /cache ext4
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
>   /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/apps_log /mnt/idd ext4
>   rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,discard,nobarrier,data=ordered
>   0 0 tmpfs /storage/remote tmpfs
>   rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,size=1024k,nr_inodes=256,mode=750,gid=1028
>   0 0 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/LTALabel /lta-label ext4
>   ro,context=u:object_r:lta_label:s0,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,data=ordered
>   0 0 securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,noatime,nodiratime 0
>   0 /dev/fuse /mnt/shell/emulated fuse
>   rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0 /dev/block/vold/179:65 /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 vfat
>   rw,dirsync,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
>   0 0 /dev/block/vold/179:65 /mnt/secure/asec vfat
>   rw,dirsync,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
>   0 0 /dev/fuse /storage/sdcard1 fuse
>   rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0